# compileLintOptionsJavaWithJavac fails with cannot find symbo

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project that has multiple build types and a few shared packages for sources (public and internal) which allow us to build releases for different stores and internal builds with different code enabled.  My gradle script is similar to as follows and you'll note it has source sets for the build type and an additional package for public or internal.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            ...
        }

        debug {
            ...
        }
    }

    configurations {
        ...
    }

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
        debug {
            ...
        }
        tester.initWith(release)
        tester {
            ...
        }

        lintOptions {
            warningsAsErrors false
            abortOnError gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("assembleRelease")
            warning 'MissingTranslation'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        release {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/release/java', 'src/public/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/release/res', 'src/public/res']
        }
        debug {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/debug/java', 'src/internal/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res', 'src/internal/res']
        }
        tester {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/tester/java', 'src/internal/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/tester/res', 'src/internal/res']
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        ...
    }

    dexOptions {
        ...
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run `./gradlew :module:compileLintOptionsJavaWithJavac` it fails with `cannot find symbol` for every class in the public or internal directories.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is having the lintOptions block within the buildTypes block.  Move it out to be a direct child of android